# how to make field search not case-sensitive in solr using solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet

In solr schema i have field as below

```
<field name="Company" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

and field type as

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

and

```
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"><analyzer type="index"><tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

when i search on this field it is case-sensitive

How i can make this field search case-insensitive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is a copyfield that converts the field in question to lowercase. Use it only for searching. A post with a similiar question :)

[How to create a case insensitive copy of a string field in SOLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053214/how-to-create-a-case-insensitive-copy-of-a-string-field-in-solr)

Comment: but the linked answer states a caveat that it can not be used for searching with wildcards.