# Solr case insensitive search

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solrnet, solrcloud

Im trying to set up a case insensitive search for bunch of XML documents. Is there a inbuilt field type that i can use? Im using Solr 5.2.1, I tried all stack overflow responses

[SOLR Case Insensitive Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240329/solr-case-insensitive-search)
[how to make field search not case-sensitive in solr using solrnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205688/how-to-make-field-search-not-case-sensitive-in-solr-using-solrnet)

I added a custom field in schema.xml which is inside
solr-5.2.1\example\example-DIH\solr\solr\schema.xml

should this field appear in schema browser in the web UI? Im also not getting it there.
this is the filed type :

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField"
        sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

this is my xml:

```
<doc>
<field name="id">
70
change.me</field>
<field name="title1" type="string_ci">
Hatton Matale
</field>
<field name="title2" type="text_general">
Kotagala Kandy
</field>
</doc>
```

this is my query :

```
title2:*kandy*
```

http://localhost:8983/solr/CaseTest/select?=title2%3A*kandy*&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: and you are not getting the result?

Comment: why are you using keyword tokeniser?

Comment: if you are not able to see the fieldType in the brower that means you are not adding it at correct place. Which of the basic config set are you using?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti : Thanks for your reply, Im getting no results. This is the response   "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
should I use some other Tokenizer? Im attaching the schema file.

Comment: here is my schema;
http://lankatop.com/schema.xml 
my filed type is string_ci 
what could be the reason its not showing in the schema browser please?

Comment: here you have created a core CaseTest...if its has its different configuration ...then you need to change in the same file of that conf folder...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below fieldType. It will break the text stream into token by white space and convert to lower case before indexing.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```