# Solr field searching, wildcards, and escaped characters

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using solr for the search functionality on my webapp. I append an "*" to the end of each user's search. So, if the search is: `foo` I change it to `filename:foo*`

This works fine, except that often a hyphen will be included in the user's search. A search of `filename:foo-bar*` returns zero results, as the hyphen removes any search results produced from the search term(s) after it. I can escape it, as `filename:foo\-bar*` but I still get zero results. If I try `filename:foo"-"*` the search returns all documents.

Any suggestions on how to get `-` and `*` to play nice with one another?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try switching from _text_ type to **solr.StrField** type, and issue a `filename:foo-bar*` search.

Comment: That solves the problem in the post. However, it requires the query to be case sensitive. Any suggestions for how to get around that?

Comment: Following the response in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2060960/935083) for creating case insensitive string type - it seems to work fine locally on test data.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've had to escape the wildcard character if anything else in the string is escaped. This is to get it to function as a wildcard; you'd think it'd make it look for the character itself, but it seems not to. Note: Escaping the * without other escaped characters seems to search exactly for the character *, and does not use it as a wildcard operator.

```
field:*and\/or* //would NOT perform a wildcarded search for "and/or"

field:\*and\/or\* //would perform wildcard search for and/or
```

To be clear, it seems like they are backwards, but that is what hass worked in my cases.

Comment: cannot reproduce this behavior, still no results.